# Rules using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am working on a project and it involves making a search via google maps then making the street space wider. The first step of the project is making the street wider because the current design is thin and focus on property. Our project will focus on the street so we need to make that bigger.

Is there a rule to manipulating google maps in such a way?

In addition, what challenges do you guys see us facing when we try to do this? on the other hand, is this something that can be easily achieved?

Thanks
Phil

Comment: " making the street wider " what do you mean by this?

Comment: You can make all roads wider by updating the `stroke` or `fill` property of the style options for it (have an experiment on https://snazzymaps.com/editor). But I don't think there is a way to update the style of a particular road only, if that's what you're after?